# Decreasing System Reserved Video RAM -- Kernel still reserves the same RAM

Tags: linux, memory, bios

I'm working with an old desktop (very old Lenovo ThinkCentre workstation) the we've repurposed into a server (RHEL7.3). It has an integrated graphics chip and I believe that's eating more RAM than it should be. The system reports that 4GB is installed, and free -m lists 3.5~ GB as usable. Looking in dmesg I can see that the OS is reserving the remaining 0.5~ GB. I attempted to reduce the video RAM being reserved in the BIOS by setting it to a fixed 128MB. However upon reboot the system has reserved the same amount of memory:

```
[redacted]$ grep memory -i dmesg | grep -i reserved
[    0.000000] Memory: 3648080k/5046272k available (6764k kernel code, 1058768k absent, 339424k reserved, 4433k data, 1680k init)
[redacted]$ grep memory -i dmesg.old | grep -i reserved
[    0.000000] Memory: 3648080k/5046272k available (6764k kernel code, 1058768k absent, 339424k reserved, 4433k data, 1680k init)
```

Have I missed some step or is this correct? I double-checked the BIOS to make sure I saved my changes but it's showing the expected settings for the video card. Is there any way I can get ahold of some of the RAM being reserved by the system or is it 'lost' and just something we'll need to work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel's not reserving RAM, it's reserving address space. Likely your workstation has no support for memory remapping, so if it needs address space below 4GB (and it will, for all kinds of things), that makes some RAM unusable. The RAM isn't reserved, there's just no place to map it so that it can be accessed.

You can check your BIOS settings for a "memory remapping" setting. If you see one, turn it on. That will cause the BIOS to remap the memory above the 4GB limit. If the BIOS has no such option, the chipset probably doesn't support such remapping.